# Zoomable AsyncImage like Instagram

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, zooming

I would like to zoom my `AsyncImage` with two fingers and when I stop zooming it should come to previous original scale `1f`.
What I could achieve is that I could zoom my image, but it doesn't work well when stop zooming action.

This is my code:

```
val imageModifer =                     Modifier
                            .size(176.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.Center)
                            .graphicsLayer(
                                scaleX = scale,
                                scaleY = scale
                            )
                            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                                detectTransformGestures { _, _, zoom, _ ->
                                    scale *= zoom
                                }
                            }
// without this below method onGloballyPositioned I can by myself zoom and outzoom the image it quite work alright.
                            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                // when adding this method I somehow does not allow me to zoom it further like it stop with minimum of zooming let's say 1.05f
                                val originalScale = 1f
                                if (scale > originalScale) {
                                    scale = originalScale
                                } else if (scale < 0.5f) {
                                    scale = 0.5f
                                }
                            }
                        AsyncImage(
                            model = painter,
                            placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_placeholder),
                            error = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_holder),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 14.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    events.invoke(Event.ToggleImageExpand)
                                }
                                .then(
                            imageModifier
                                ),
                            contentDescription = "Image",
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        )
```

I also have tried with this library
https://github.com/mxalbert1996/Zoomable

but my painter is not from resources, but it has got string `imagePath`
so I have tried something like:

```
                        Zoomable {
                            val painter: Painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = imagePath)
                            val size = painter.intrinsicSize


                            Image(
                                painter = painter,
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .aspectRatio(size.width / size.height)
                                    .fillMaxSize()
                            )
```

or.. the same with `AsyncImage`, but looks like it doesn't load this `painter` well.

error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Size is unspecified
```

without using size it doesn't show any image.

i.e.

```
                            val painter: Painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = imagePath)
                            Image(
                                painter = painter,
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .aspectRatio(1f)
                                    .fillMaxSize()
                            )
```

Thanks for any help!:)

solved by using default code library + some additional code:

```
suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectTransformGestures(
    panZoomLock: Boolean = false,
    onGesture: (centroid: Offset, pan: Offset, zoom: Float, rotation: Float) -> Unit,
    onAllGesturesEnd: () -> Unit,
) {
    val processingEvents = mutableListOf<PointerId>()
    awaitEachGesture {
        var rotation = 0f
        var zoom = 1f
        var pan = Offset.Zero
        var pastTouchSlop = false
        val touchSlop = viewConfiguration.touchSlop
        var lockedToPanZoom = false
        val input = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
        processingEvents.add(input.id) // remember a newly started gesture
        do {
            val event = awaitPointerEvent()
            val canceled = event.changes.fastAny { it.isConsumed }
            if (!canceled) {
                val zoomChange = event.calculateZoom()
                val rotationChange = event.calculateRotation()
                val panChange = event.calculatePan()
                if (!pastTouchSlop) {
                    zoom *= zoomChange
                    rotation += rotationChange
                    pan += panChange
                    val centroidSize = event.calculateCentroidSize(useCurrent = false)
                    val zoomMotion = kotlin.math.abs(1 - zoom) * centroidSize
                    val rotationMotion =
                        kotlin.math.abs(rotation * PI.toFloat() * centroidSize / 180f)
                    val panMotion = pan.getDistance()
                    if (zoomMotion > touchSlop ||
                        rotationMotion > touchSlop ||
                        panMotion > touchSlop
                    ) {
                        pastTouchSlop = true
                        lockedToPanZoom = panZoomLock && rotationMotion < touchSlop
                    }
                }
                if (pastTouchSlop) {
                    val centroid = event.calculateCentroid(useCurrent = false)
                    val effectiveRotation = if (lockedToPanZoom) 0f else rotationChange
                    if (effectiveRotation != 0f ||
                        zoomChange != 1f ||
                        panChange != Offset.Zero
                    ) {
                        onGesture(centroid, panChange, zoomChange, effectiveRotation)
                    }
                    event.changes.fastForEach {
                        if (it.positionChanged()) {
                            it.consume()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (!canceled && event.changes.fastAny { it.pressed })
        processingEvents.remove(input.id)
        if (processingEvents.isEmpty()) {
            onAllGesturesEnd()
        }
    }
}
```